# Google Maps Api not displaying map into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

This question has been asked a couple of times, but no response has worked for me. I tried to add width and height to container div

```
<div style="height:900px;width:1024px;"> 
    Mapa
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Tried either to add the domListener Event to google maps object or just using jquery document.ready function

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
$(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });
```

I created this **[`Jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/pdwxtwyx/)** to show my point, I know that I am missing the API key but this doesn't seems to be the problem.

I don't know what I am missing here. Any ideas?

I know that I am missing the api key

**Snippet with code Below**

```js
function initialize(){
    $(".map").each(function(){
        var centerLat = 52.5230809;
        var centerLong = 13.3999976;
        console.log(centerLat);
        console.log(centerLong);
        var centerLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLong);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: parseFloat(centerLat), lng: parseFloat(centerLong)},
          zoom: 8,
          scrollwheel: false,
          draggable:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        console.log(map);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: centerLatLong,
            map: map
        });
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
$(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });
```

```html
<div style="height:900px;width:1024px;"> 
    Mapa
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add css to map div.

```
   <div style="height:900px;width:1024px;"> 
        Mapa
        <div style="height:900px;width:1024px;" id="map" class="map"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh god! thanks always saw that you have to add styling to container not the map itself, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [@egvrcn 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397840/622813). But why are you using `.each()` ? You want to use **multiple maps** ?

**Yes ?**

```
function initialize() {
    $(".map").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // ...
        var map = new google.maps.Map($this[0], mapOptions);
        // ...
    });
}
```

**No ?**, so do just...

```
function initialize() {
    // ...
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's because I want to use multiple maps, the id will change. Thanks

Comment: + You dont really need `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` @Cheluis